# How do I give other users permission to access ntfs partition?

Tags: permissions, ntfs

Only adm users have access to the ntfs partition, how do I change this?

Edited: My ubuntu is 22.04

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting permission for NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223016/setting-permission-for-ntfs-partition)